# Kaspersky Endpoint Security 11: не стартует демон

Tags: linux, kaspersky

После запуска скрипта postinstall.pl все установилось норм, но выходит такая ошибка:

> Starting klnagent: Failed to start klnagent64.service: Unit
> klnagent64.service not found.

С чем это едят? Как исправить?

Comment: А как и куда ты его ставил? `linux` - довольно общее понятие.

Comment: На Arch с помощью dpkg

Comment: Ох, на ubuntu я бы помог.